# Get data from any items in array

Tags: postgresql-9.5

PosgreSQL 9.5

Field type: **jsonb**

Here json

```
{
  "options": [
    {
      "name": "method"
    },
    {
      "name": "flavor"
    },
    {
      "name": "weight",
      "value": {
        "name": "300g"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here query that get value of item (**weight**) with index = 2 from array:

```
SELECT 
id, 
product.data #>'{title,en}' AS title_en,
product.data #>>'{options, 2, value, name }' as options_weight_value
FROM product
```

Nice. It's work fine.

But the problem that **weight** can be in any index in array. First or second and so on.

So I need to get value of **name** (**300g**) in node "weight" .
I need smt like this:

```
  SELECT 
    id, 
    product.data #>'{title,en}' AS title_en,
    product.data #>>'{options, *, value, name, weight }' as options_weight_value
    FROM product
```

Is it  possible ?

Comment: Can you change the JSON structure? It would be a lot more efficient to do something like `{"method": "...", "flavor": "...", "weight": "300g"}`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, I can't change json.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was added my solution

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution:

```
SELECT 
id,
p.data #>'{title,en}' AS title_en,
p.data #>'{weight,qty}' AS weight_qty,
(select * 
from jsonb_array_elements(p.data -> 'options') AS options_array
where 
 options_array ->> 'name' = 'weight'
) #>'{value,name}' as options_weight
from product p
```

And now find value of **weight**(if exist) **in any** array's item. In this example it = **300g**